# My desktop icons have changed, specifically for chrome, edge and brave links

Tags: icons

Ive been learning more about computers lately which means ive been trying to things and settings.  Now some of my deskto icons have changed to a different picture.  The ones shown are links for chrome, brave and edge. Im using windows 10.

[image of my icons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tpLLu.png)

Answer (score 0):

It usually depends what your default browser is set to under 'Default programs'

Comment: My default browser is set to Brave. All three examples in the picture are for different browsers though.

Comment: Whats the target if you right click on 'School resources' and choose properties?

Comment: "C:\Program Files\BraveSoftware\Brave-Browser\Application\brave.exe"                                Its just the homepage of the brave browser with some bookmarks for school.